# Add Image or Video to Gallery in api29 and above

Tags: android, gallery, mime-types, mediastore, android-contentresolver

**This code only works for api29 and lower,**
But it does not work for api 29 above

Of course, there is also a problem with saving video in the code below
Video time is displayed in the gallery at 00:00

```
fun Context.addToGallery(file: File) {
    if (file.absolutePath.contains(".mp4", ignoreCase = true)){
        contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, ContentValues().apply {
            put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4")
            put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, file.absolutePath)
        })
    }else{
        contentResolver.insert(Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, ContentValues().apply {
            put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpg")
            put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, file.absolutePath)
        })
    }
}
```